# Sonarqube integration in hudson and SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube, hudson, sonar-runner

I am trying to run sonarqube as part of a hudson job. I installed sonarqube 5.4 and sonar plugin 2.0.1 in hudson.

But when the job runs I get the following error, where do I provide SVN authentication details for Sonar?

I already provided SVN details as part of my job but sonar is unable to read that properties.

Can't I make sonar to read source downloaded by hudson instead of again trying to connect to SVN?

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project MyProject: Error when executing blame for file Myfile.java: svn: E170001: Authentication required for ' Subversion repository'
```

Comment: Which properties (`-Dsonar.xxx`) did you pass to the sonar job ? (either from config file or command line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [SVN Plugin documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SVN+Plugin) you should most likely use `sonar.svn.username` and `sonar.svn.password.secured` properties.

The setting of such properties can be done in various places. Either in your project definition (see [Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)) or just follow the documentation of the [Scanner for Jenkins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) (for example using `-Dsonar.svn.username`).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. But in jenkins log lot of verbose log messages are getting dispalyed, is there any way to hide all not required logs and just display final report url?